# Write char in line as many times as the length of previous line

Tags: vim

I would like to write a char as many times as the length of the previous line

Starting point:

```
This is a line and I want to write a char under it.
```

I want to write char `=` as many times as the length of this line. This is the result I would like to obtain:

```
This is a line and I want to write a char under it.
===================================================
```

How I can achieve this result with the most reduced key/commands combination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect there is something shorter but the following works with the cursor starting over the initial line:

```
Yp:s/./=/g
```

It duplicates the line (`Yp`), then replaces each character on the new line with an `=` (`:s/./=/g`)

## Update

An even shorter version from [Doktor OSwaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011106/write-char-in-line-as-many-times-as-the-length-of-previous-line#comment80969159_47011192)

```
YpVr=
```

Duplicates the line, selects it and replaces all characters with =

And, if you are using this a lot, it'll be even shorter as a macro.

Comment: It would be a little shorter, if you just remove the `V` ;).
Since `:s` in contrast to `:%s` only replaces on the current line, it is not needed

Comment: Good optimisation.

Comment: Even shorter would be: `YpVr=`. Feel free to add it to your answer if you like.

Comment: Very nice. Updated.

Comment: Little note for those that have mapped `Y` to `y$`, it becomes `yypVr=`.